# Is Phonegap capable of converting all CSS3 transitions?

Tags: css, cordova

Is Phonegap capable of converting all CSS3 transitions or should we avoid some of them?

Comment: Phonegap provides a stepping stone between Javascript and native API's. It doesn't know anything about CSS. You can use what ever css the device is capable of using - http://caniuse.com/

Comment: So you say the CSS will be worked by the device itself, so if it has modern browsers CSS3 transitions will be visible.

Comment: Kind of. You need to research the capabilities of each platforms WebView ([Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html), [iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/)) as this is what Phonegap uses to display your app. Your app is essentially opened in an embedded browser. That's why you can use html, css, javascript etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Phonegap uses a Webview to display your page.

in most devices the Webview uses webkit to render pages. So what ever works in other webkit browsers (Google chrome, for example), should work with phonegap.

read more here:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/4.0.0/guide_hybrid_webviews_index.md.html

Comment: Great, thank you! So can we say that:  "even there's no browser in that gadget which supports webkit, we don't have to think about that because Phonegap supports webkit itself without any browser support?"

Comment: not exactly.
I think most the devices that phonegap compiles to, just hav webkit browsers as a native control, but not sure about that.

Answer (score 1):

You should check every CSS and javascript feature you want to use on http://caniuse.com/

You should check the columns iOS Safari for iOS apps and Android Browser for android apps (not chrome for android, because it usually has better support than Android Browser and the android webview is based on the Android Browser, not on chrome)